# Jquery select variable by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the content of a select option which is specified by the selected options.

I can get the selected options to tell me the data-parent but I can't use that to get the text of the parent option.

```
<select id="addCatSelectCats" multiple="multiple">
    <option id="Cat55" data-parent="5">Parent Cat</option>
    <option id="Cat357" data-parent="55">Sub Cat</option>
</select>

$(document).on('change', '#addCatSelectCats',function() {
    $("#addCatSelectCats option").each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':selected')){
            var dataparent = $(this).attr('data-parent');
            if(dataparent > 0){
                var parent = $('#Cat'+dataparent).text();
                alert(parent);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2ttgwvug/ Your code is working here.

Comment: It already works. You should check before posting such questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could do with a little less code

```
$(document).on('change', '#addCatSelectCats',function() {
    var parent = $("#addCatSelectCats option:selected").text();
                alert(parent);     
});
```